# Add various colors to groups in Vega radial chart

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, vega

So I made this chart: [Vega-radial-chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6SgBY6AK1jcAdpAA04KAHdGAExbYwogAw7FESCkbV8W3fqWR0rPN1iMAXsi2QAZswUgrD6jPQANrBaANpKEKAQUVD+qC44kLB46ABOeACCMtQBLvJQFIGs8WA6dACsAEwG0VDsjDJqWsCQ9YS2rinoWblQqPVa+r3oAB5aAGx0FQCceYl4yIQDdDoAjAC+4WBr1RGbhrHFkMgNmdk9kAUBRa4T0141tfWNOM2t7Qmd3Qq9-TiDkBhRjhbjMoEkFktVhtottNpEapADq5COg1Kcct8LoVipYHpA6g0mi0ZG08B0utRzn05H9ZoClutNrDovDooj0HFXPUZMgUgAlVGMVjBWaXa44FY7KL4p5Et5kj4Uqm-Ep0kZaKpg+aLP7LRkwqWs6VIhLwbgpHn8wXCzFinFSwwE55gV4k95QT6UzHUgZqoFgFb-cE6krlaFRZlRI37DmHHnKVQaRC27FaADMegdj0JL2JpPJXzpKsD-3pEr0Qe1Wn1EcN7M5CUTmlmrEIanQ81c8abycjEXrh2MpjJLbbHbjyAT6k0fZdexiseRjAWqTwsAqhEY9wRrfbnYSxzRWRyACo06QclkWAAKPfoa8AcmS7ByD4AlG-IEyIEoALqKKw71COF5wHVxnwxLMsSuZBghwMIHn7dRqzyKBCF5eBjgVANZlgZB4DsFJsElKBqBSbhWwASWedYsyQ51NTQjCsJQsF8MI4jZjIijCGo7AKlnFkWmdNNUMgdCUkwmRsJIxJ2PNTjSPIqjnjTQSo2E8wxIkqSZNw+SiKwWTuJU7BRHU+itDKbTmOk1i5IIhSjK45TeOeMoLJdTTgRsySWIlfTHMM4zXL4rAxk815nQAdl83SNUCjisE1SATLc4jIu8sAAA44v8sAUrwoL+JcniwoEuivOQnBQSYvy7JwQqDJKpSytUzLqoDf4dPypriuS0rTKwczKqi6tZJ6hqA3KRKnJStKwo80aspWFLJuwvqkvm0Lngi5bOpWUS6vigK2P6o7Up2jL9udFZRFmdalmss6kouhbngq+dLIlZ7xNs7CLqK17BvSrA1Ju6sxge-6NRml6nLeq7ho627YuO-Kg2asGQcW8Non-UC8E+WA3HNVBgMQudKcMPAAE90KXHpEK+6UklXdFimaXx-ACVw2bSDnIE8wxD0F3NucCVxRePFw8ZqSKWZp+nDjZ+AAGtvkVqAPGQAJnT++qRzALXLp49hadCU3TN-FmFepqA6YZhJSZSVBWACTA8hN5BhkIQyoD3VhUDoWmdAAam5XkBTUIURRN9A4KgUOAH14y-Sm7epyBHcOF23Y9zX7aOX3-cgQPg9plYI5kS1o9j7dKesRPIEr1PJ3TxC1kp+cbZhP8AMMBBAlgimo1Ak0PSHyDCeV1wAnqZBUgb6VPWKEJBi5kweewSAe1ICohYJvFnHIrQiaKKC1G4DAVWaICEgg84db11xW7TuXtmiEC8QnyAzQCBSUEc6uHNDHbeUFV6hCgOgbKmFkBlExOwZAahsr4UxNlNw8AVhqHONFUQ7AKhqGipiMo7B0BpngG4SAYBe4Rn7t4QwGAUhq0TghMeeJgEJFSPAZehg3DkXJrme+Dt0AvlllBY4ZocFNBZkcaSvIZFF39JvPwktGzTkQGAUgBUhaVUMBbcWW81G4GQCYfAWidFywNLI3c45FFZw8AEXm4t4DD1cP-QB2tlwvwSEDBSn97bGyLkkciatObQXFCoRAzBxEm35hkGWRIJbOK1OzGWYAw5gFvB2IODAdoAFoVhvhPJuFcaR1ybl0d7E4iTDGqJSXMNJZwMlgHLnktqJTlwonKRuLcws0KojFl5ZJyJBmJP6cSWu1pE5c1cRiD4U8n7eP1ind+eioAUXmFaGONoXFuIWXMpZusVkrDbsoKpRczQWijtMpJRiGlXKmTs4IEy7DcACHgRgIZoxZxGQkYAAAdSAAAFf6QKcB5w7NkvAQcQgPnWg+f8YAHx0BWG4d8LSHwAFIHx5CBQAZQMuC1pOTUBwr8SkRFeKrZuWJeXOF71EVbA7hnW2lUjDcCoIZFmPy8SOJSc0O0O8UjIKFrbecH8-wgDWEAA)

It is based on this discussion here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vega-js/radial%7Csort:date/vega-js/Ymj4yOfgMA8/gnhRhK75CAAJ

So my question is, how would I go about making the various groups have various color schemes? I tried all sorts of array / object structures for the color scales, but nothings seems to come together.

Comment: Each arc/group to have different color schemes (blues, reds, etc.,) with each sector Brightness varying? If I understand the requirement correctly, I wonder what is the usecase please?

Comment: The usecase is that I am building a personality chart based on the 16 personalities model (https://www.16personalities.com/articles/our-theory). So basically, I have 5 main categories: mind, energy, nature, tactics and identity, which should all have a main color, like for example: blue, red, yellow, green and purple. And 10 subcategories: extrovert/introvert, intuitive/observant, thinking/feeling, judging/prospecting, assertive/turbulent. These should also have the color of the main category, but the intensity of the color should increase based on how much the person scored for each.